# Internationalization of JSON in assets folder

Tags: java, android

I have a JSON file stored locally in assets folder -

My JSON in assets folder is -

```
[
  {
    "title": "1",
    "message": "Hi"
  },
  {
    "title": "2",
    "message": "Bye"
  },
  {
    "title": "3",
    "message": "Hello"
  }
]
```

This is currently in English. When I change my phone language to French, is it possible that the content of the JSON is in French.
How do I achieve this without having 1 more file specifically for French in assets folder? Or is it the only solution that I need to have 1 more file for French in assets folder?

Comment: did u try to keep it as a `String` resource in each locale and read the string and parse the JSON value.?

Comment: Create separate string folder for different language.

Comment: @SivakumarS no i did not do like that...Can you explain me briefly please how i could do that? would be helpful...

Comment: Check @Vladyslav answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do it directly, but you can use this nice workaround:

Name your assets as follows: `file-en.json`, `file-de.json`, etc.
In your english `strings.xml` define a string:

```
<string name="jsonFile">file-en.json</string>
```

in DE strings:

```
<string name="jsonFile">file-de.json</string>
```

And now you can get the asset by name, which is stored in translated string resource.

Answer (score -1):

Create Folder like value-en and value-fr.In that string file mention your string with appropriate language.Try like a below code.

```
List<Model> modellist = new ArrayList();
for(i=0;i<reposece.size();i++){
Model model = new Model();
model.addTitle(response.get(getString(R.string.title)))
model.addMessage(response.get(getString(R.string.message)))
modellist.add(model);
}
```